# sorting a table column using react bootstrap not working

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am looking into using the react-bootstrap-table library mostly because it seems to be easy to sort columns.
Do I need to stick to the structure used in this library?

My old project is using regular tables and it looks really confusing.

This library looks so easy, I was hoping I'd be able to use elements of the library and not all such as the sort table feature.

I've been looking on here but I'm not finding anything regarding using regular Tables

```
http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table
```

I'm going to assume I need to use the correct library to get it to work.
such as this.

```
<BootstrapTable ref='table' data={ products }>
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='id' isKey={ true } dataSort={ true }>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

but i can't do this.

```
<Table ref='table' data={ products }>
<thead>
<tr>
<th dataField='id' isKey={ true } dataSort={ true }>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you certainly can't use pieces like that solo end component tag. `<th></TableHeaderColumn></th>` is never going to work because there is no corresponding `<TableHeaderColumn>`.

So the thing is, `<TableHeaderColumn>` is a component, not a tag. What you are doing is using *properties* of this component and inserting them as *attributes* of the `<th>` tag. This won't work. I won't say never, because in some cases there are properties that directly translate to tag attributes, but in general - just don't.

If you're going to use component libraries, there are some cases where you can use pieces of components, such as subcomponents, if they are exported and incorporated correctly. I'm afraid this isn't the case with this library. It's meant to work as a whole. The components for the headers provide sorting instructions/data for the functionality of the table body components. That is, the table body components use data provided from the table headers to determine what order the data in your table should be sorted.

I hope this makes sense. In short, this table library works as a whole, not a part. I'm sure with enough time one could pick apart the library and make pieces of it work without the whole but it might be easier/faster just to use the entire library and rebuild your table.

Side notes:

Looking through the [React-Bootstrap-Table documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/table/) it first states it's deprecated (I'm mentioning this because your full code hasn't been shown and I'm not sure what version you've imported).

Here's the non-deprecated version: [React-Bootstrap-Table2](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/)

Comment: thank you this is what i was thinking. I'm soo utterly confused with react. I have no clue how to understand or grasp this stuff it goes from beginner to extremely hard advanced stuff with no documentation